Magento 2 GooglePay payment method setup issue with shipping address
In magento 2, we need to setup GooglePay with their APIs.
we are following below demo and it's document to show button.
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos
Now, When we are tring to pass selected shipping address from magento to googlepay(in googlepay request) at that time as per document it is allowing only two parameters "allowedCountryCodes" and "phoneNumberRequired". Is it possible to pass selected shipping address from magento to googlepay?
What is
 paymentDataRequest.callbackIntents = ["SHIPPING_ADDRESS", "SHIPPING_OPTION", "PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"];
Does it help me to pass a selected address in googlepay request?
I want to pass selected shipping address in googlepay API request.
